# Error can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python

I'm getting the following error:

```
     if len(new_send_times) > rate_limit * window * self._throttle:
        TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

**This is the code:**

```
if len(new_send_times) > rate_limit * window * self._throttle:
                    # Sleep the remainder of the window period.
                    delta = now - new_send_times[0]
                    total_seconds = (delta.microseconds + (delta.seconds +
                                                           delta.days * 24 * 3600) * 10 ** 6) / 10 ** 6
                    delay = window - total_seconds
                    if delay > 0:
                        sleep(delay)

                recent_send_times.append(now)
                # end of throttling
```

**the values it uses are**

```
if len([]) > 1.0 * 2.0 * 0.5:
```

**Update:** 
I changed it to below and it works, but I still don't understand the error or if want I'm doing it correct:

```
 if len(new_send_times) > float(rate_limit) * float(window) * float(self._throttle):
```

Comment: How have you determined that those are the values being used?

Comment: @jonrsharpe my good old friend print(val) :)

Comment: @Spike *just* before the operation runs? Bear in mind that a string counts as a sequence, but may look like a number, which would explain why using `float` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty self-explonatory. You are performing operation in the form

```
list * float # or other sequence * float
```

which is forbidden in python, you can

```
numeric * float # "traditional" multiplication
```

or

```
list * int # creates concatenated copies of the list provided
```

So investigate your code, check which object is a list and convert it to the number, as the code logic suggests that this is your intended behaviour.

Examples:

```
[1] * 3 = [1,1,1]

[1] * 1.5 # ERROR

1 * 1.5 == 1.5

float([1]) * 1.5 == 1.5

"1" * 1.5 # ERROR

float("1") * 1.5 == 1.5
```

Comment: I have updated the OP. however I'm now doing list * float still and it works, why ?

Comment: No, you are not anymore. float() converted list to the float, so you are now performing float * float, which is just fine

Comment: A `sequence` is not necessarily a `list` - I think it is probably a `str` in this case, you can't convert a `list` to `float` ("`float()` argument must be a string or a number").

Comment: I see, now it makes sense

Answer (score 1):

The error message

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

tells you that at least one of

```
len(new_send_times), rate_limit, window, self._throttle
```

is not a number, as you suspect, but some kind of sequence.

The fact that you `print` these values and see what you expect, along with the fact that using `float()` on the values makes the code work, suggests strongly that one of them is a string representation of a number (e.g. `'1.0'`) rather than the number itself - `str` in Python counts as a `sequence`.

`len()` will always return an `int` (or raise an error!), so there's no need to worry about that, but one of the other three is probably a string. You need to source where the values are coming from (`[raw_]input`? Parsed file?) and make sure they're being converted to numerical types at the appropriate point (the earlier the better, as in other contexts you may get more subtle problems).

To tell the difference, when `print`ing the values to check, you could do e.g.

```
print(rate_limit, type(rate_limit))
```

Comment: I forgot about the type() function! very helpful thanks.